# ".NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003131" missing error

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

After installing ".NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2.1-003177",

[image]

Whenever I am going to create new "asp.net core" web application, I am getting below error, looks like it always refer some old configuration.

How to resolve this, please suggest!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the SDK version in your `global.json` in Solution Items. Change it to `1.0.0-preview2.1-003177`.

[image]

Comment: from where I can find the global json file?

Comment: You should have it in your Solution Explorer, directly underneath the solution name. I will attach a screenshot

Comment: Or just remove that line and it will always use the latest

Comment: @Tseng I find that a bad practice, because your team should use the same tooling version. In this way, you cannot accidentally upgrade to the .NET Core 1.1 tooling if your project still targets .NET Core 1.0

Comment: @shaziaperween I have not found a way yet, but it might change in VS2017

Comment: FYI: If you need to download previous runtimes/SDKs: go [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md).
Recently setup the project I've been working on on another machine and had some trouble finding the download for the version it was on.

Comment: @steamrolla how do you know which version to specify if downloading from that page?  I downloaded `DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.4.exe` how do I know which preview version is installed from that?