# How to change the .NET Core SDK version that VS2015 uses?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've installed VS2017 and it totally broke my VS2015 install.  When I try to create a new .net core web application project I get the error below:

I do not have version `preview2-a-003177` in my `c:\program files\dotnet\sdk` folder and I can't seem to find that version online anywhere either.

So how can I change the the version of the .net core sdk (to something I do have installed) that VS2015 template uses?

[image]

P.S. I know that I can add a global.json that points to a specific dotnet sdk version, but I'd rather not do that.  That scenario is already addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874537/net-core-sdk-version-1-0-0-preview2-003131-missing-error).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you can't.

VS 2015 use only `.xproj` file, while latest SDK (since preview3 or 4) use old-new '.csproj'. Latest SDK will try to convert (migrate) you project to .csproj.

You should switch to VS2017 to use latest SDK or stick with `preview2-1` to work in VS0215.

Check that you really have required SDK version in your `c:\program files\dotnet\sdk` (my installations of VS 2017 does not removed any previous sdk installed). If required, you can download any version of old SDK [from here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md)

Comment: I wish I could switch to VS2017.  But .net core compiled on it won't run on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, while VS2015 compiled ones will.  Also, I need my Resharper.

Comment: Then you need `global.json` and old SDK version. VS2015 and VS2017 successfully work side-by-side.